Auto-complete custom style of the list in vuetify
I want to customize the dropdown list,
with class of vuetify or with custom class.
How can I do it?
This is the image of list
I tried to check with F12 and see what the class of the list is, but every time the list closes immediately.
I also tried searching maybe using the item-prpos property or using the menu-props property, but couldn't.
This is my code:
<v-autocomplete
        :items="dataItems"
        clearable
        class=""
        variant="solo"
        rounded="pill"
        bg-color="blue"
        clear-icon="mdi-close"
        menu-icon="none"
        density="comfortable"
        flat="true"
        @blur="onInput"
      />

Maybe you will know?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To customize the list you can use .v-autocomplete__content => .v-list (or .v-list-item to customize items)


const {createApp, ref} = Vue;
const {createVuetify} = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({});

app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
.v-autocomplete__content {
  .v-list {
    border: 1px solid orange;
  }
  .v-list-item {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-autocomplete
    :items="['Test1', 'Test2']"
    clearable
    class=""
    variant="solo"
    rounded="pill"
    bg-color="blue"
    clear-icon="mdi-close"
    menu-icon="none"
    density="comfortable"
  />
</div>



